# post image to server using http post multipart/form-data request [flutter-web]

Tags: image, flutter, http-post

I am trying to upload the image to server using http package,
here is the screenshot from postman
[image]
so far I have been following this link https://rodolfohernan20.blogspot.com/2019/12/upload-files-to-server-with-flutter-web.html
and here is part of the code to send the image

```
var url = Uri.parse("http:xxxxxxx");
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    request.fields['user_id'] = '1';
    request.fields['_method'] = 'put';
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        'file', _imageFile,
        contentType: new MediaType('application', 'octet-stream'),
        filename: "example"));

    request.send().then((response) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) print("sent");
    });
```

`imageFile` is List of int(`List<int>`) where `imageFile=Base64Decoder().convert(result.toString().split(",").last);`
the respond that I get is always respond status= 400, is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
//URL
String baseUrl = "https:xxxxx";

var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(baseUrl));
request.headers.addAll(headers);

request.files.add(
  http.MultipartFile(
    'file',
     File(_imageFile.path).readAsBytes().asStream(),
     File(_imageFile.path).lengthSync(),
     filename: _imageFile.path.split("/").last,
   ),
);

// Other fields
request.fields['user_id'] = '1';
request.fields['_method'] = 'put';

var response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   // do something...
} else {
   // do something...
}
```